# how to add file manager to my flutter IOS app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

im working on both IOS and Android . for android i used the file_manager package now what i want to is that file manager for IOS also but unfortunately the file_manager package is not support for IOS so can someone guide me or same package like this.

Comment: you can try to use the file_picker package https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker

Comment: yah but this package is for picking files and i want complete file manager like file manager package have..